# Using .Include method when calling stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a simple controller and view that takes a user input string, filters a single table, and displays the results.

I am using a stored procedure to effect the search on the database.

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
    var DBdata = db.WUI_searchDatabases(null,null,searchString,null,null).ToList<Core_Databases>();
    return View(DBdata);
}
```

All well and good.

However, the next step is to also display the data from related tables.

From my research, I see lots of examples like the next snippet below, where the 'include' is used.

```
var courses = db.Courses.Include(c => c.Department);
return View(courses.ToList());
```

Great, but I am struggling to see how to do the same thing with me using a stored procedure for populating my Core_Databases, and not LINQ.

Any tips or pointer appreciated - seem to be going around in circles with Google!

### -------------------------------------------------------------

So given responses so far, seems I have hit a brick wall.
Going to post code.
My aim is to filter 1 table, but be able to show resultant records from all 3 related tables.

TBH I am not sure yet, if I want to display in 1 View, or utilize Partials or even View Components. I am just learning and thought that 1 view would be easiest for now !!
So a this stage - just 'a' way of doing this would be a start.

Table: Core_Databases

```
    public partial class Core_Databases
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Core_Databases()
    {
        this.Core_Schemas = new HashSet<Core_Schemas>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int C_id { get; set; }
    public string C_linkedServerName { get; set; }
    public string C_dataServerName { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> database_id { get; set; }
// other ....

    public virtual Core_Servers Core_Servers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Core_Schemas> Core_Schemas { get; set; }
}
```

Table : Core_Schemas

```
public partial class Core_Schemas
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Core_Schemas()
    {
        this.Core_Objects = new HashSet<Core_Objects>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int C_databaseID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int schema_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> principal_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Core_Databases Core_Databases { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Core_Objects> Core_Objects { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public class Core_DatabasesController : Controller
{
    private GBSS_DST_1Entities1 db = new GBSS_DST_1Entities1();

    public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {
        var DBdata = db.WUI_searchDatabases(null,null,searchString,null,null).ToList<Core_Databases>();
        return View(DBdata);
    }
}
```

Stored Procedure:

I am only using a 'play' SProc at the moment while I see how all this works out.
No point in developing complex code until the UI principals can bee seen to work.
The final version will be a lot more complex. 
E.g. finding an entry in table A that has 3 matching records in table B, 1 of which was has max(attribute)=XYZ ... and 2 matching records in another table C if else blah bah ...
Which is really why I did not feel straight EF+LINQ would be a good idea.

But seeing as people are asking - this is what I am using for my testing.
It returns data in the same structure as the Model 'Core_Databases'

```
ALTER procedure [MD16].[WUI_searchDatabases](
    @id int = null
    ,@dataServerName nvarchar(128) = null
    ,@name nvarchar(128) = null
    ,@compatability_level tinyint = null
    ,@collation_name nvarchar(128) = null
)
AS
--SET FMTONLY OFF
set nocount on 

DECLARE
    @sql        nvarchar(MAX),                               
    @paramlist  nvarchar(4000)                        

-- Base Query
    SELECT @sql =  '' +
        'SELECT ' + 
            '[_id] as [C_id]
            ,[_linkedServerName] as [C_linkedServerName]
            ,[_dataServerName] as [C_dataServerName]
            ,[name],[database_id],[source_database_id],[owner_sid],[create_date],[compatibility_level],[collation_name],[user_access],[user_access_desc],[is_read_only],[is_auto_close_on],[is_auto_shrink_on],[state],[state_desc],[is_in_standby],[is_cleanly_shutdown],[is_supplemental_logging_enabled],[snapshot_isolation_state],[snapshot_isolation_state_desc],[is_read_committed_snapshot_on],[recovery_model],[recovery_model_desc],[page_verify_option],[page_verify_option_desc],[is_auto_create_stats_on],[is_auto_update_stats_on],[is_auto_update_stats_async_on],[is_ansi_null_default_on],[is_ansi_nulls_on],[is_ansi_padding_on],[is_ansi_warnings_on],[is_arithabort_on],[is_concat_null_yields_null_on],[is_numeric_roundabort_on],[is_quoted_identifier_on],[is_recursive_triggers_on],[is_cursor_close_on_commit_on],[is_local_cursor_default],[is_fulltext_enabled],[is_trustworthy_on],[is_db_chaining_on],[is_parameterization_forced],[is_master_key_encrypted_by_server],[is_published],[is_subscribed],[is_merge_published],[is_distributor],[is_sync_with_backup],[service_broker_guid],[is_broker_enabled],[log_reuse_wait],[log_reuse_wait_desc],[is_date_correlation_on],[is_cdc_enabled],[is_encrypted],[is_honor_broker_priority_on] ' + 
        'FROM MD16.Core_Databases WHERE 1=1 ' 

IF @id IS NOT NULL SELECT @sql += ' AND [_id] = @id';
IF @dataServername IS NOT NULL SELECT @sql += ' AND [_dataServerName] = @dataServerName';
IF @name IS NOT NULL SELECT @sql += ' AND [name] = @name' ;
IF @compatability_level IS NOT NULL SELECT @sql += ' AND [compatability_level] = @compatability_level';
IF @collation_name IS NOT NULL SELECT @sql += ' AND [collation_name] = @collation_name' ;

SELECT @paramlist = '@id     int,                         
                     @dataServerName    nvarchar(128),
                     @name nvarchar(128),
                     @compatability_level tinyint,
                     @collation_name nvarchar(128)'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,
                    @id, @dataServername, @name, @compatability_level, @collation_name
```

Comment: can you show your SP and models ?

Comment: I would that you can't, since the `.Include(...)` extension method influences the SQL query to retrieve extra data, which is something that can't be done when you use an SP. Unless of course, you modify the SP, which kind of makes the usage of `.Include(...)` obsolete, since it is already hardcoded in the SP.

Comment: Since what you get back from the stored procedure call isn't an `IQueryable` (a "query in the making"), but an already populated list of data, you cannot add an `.Include()` statement to that. You would have to handle this *inside* the stored procedure, possibly by means of being able to specify a parameter in the stored procedure call or something

Comment: sure for including code - on it now ...

Comment: Ok, so i think the answers have made a penny drop in my head as to how EF works - and why Stored Procs + EF really don't gel very well.  I'll leave open for a while in case someone comes with a surprise answer .... butthink the answer is : it can't be done !!

Comment: you still didn't put your SP no ?

Comment: Sampath, the reason in simply that the SProc I am using currently is just a 'play'.  I did not want people to see it and think 'why is he using a Sproc  & why is it so badly designed.  However, I'll post as you seem keen !!

Comment: The closest you can get is by [returning multiple result sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) from your sproc and glue them together in client code.

Comment: Hi Gert, was just experimenting with that option, so having you suggest it gives me confidence that it might be the best way to go . Controller calls SProc, gather the multiple RS into ViewModel, send to View/Partials. Seems to be working at least in my little prototype.  If you post this as a reply, I'll mark you as the Correct Answer :)

Comment: Maybe you'd like to post (an excerpt of) your solution when you've got it working satisfactorily, maybe after meeting some thorns and thistles along the way. I never applies this myself, so I can't do much more than copy the link. A proved solution is more interesting.